# Статус запущенного бота на python в области уведомлений Windows

Tags: python, ос

Собрал Telegram-бота на Python, который по запросу от пользователей читает и отправляет данные с СУБД на этом же компьютере. Запускаю бота по main.pyw, так как окно, которое появляется при запуске main.py, могут случайно закрыть. Для того чтобы бота остановить, в диспетчере задач завершаю процесс pythonw.exe или pyw.exe. Как сделать чтобы при запущенном main.pyw в области уведомления появлялся значок с кнопкой «Выход», завершающий процесс pythonw.exe или pyw.exe?

Answer (score 3):

может я не буду сильно оригинален от первого ответа, но покажу свой пример, как я это решил в свое время через pystray, есть отличия в реализации...

установим pystray

```
pip install pystray
```

Собственно, сам код ( я его почистил, но тут раб. пример)

```
import pystray
from PIL import Image
import os
import psutil
import sys

def on_quit_callback():
    os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)

image = Image.open("icon.png")
menu_items = (("Выход", None, on_quit_callback),)
icon = pystray.Icon("name", image, "My icon", menu_items)
icon.run()
```

и обратите внимание чтобы закрыть приложение я использую `os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)`, вместо `sys.exit(`), что не совсем корректно (тут все от необходимости зависит), так что если Вам требуется что бы приложение закрылось штатно используйте `sys.exit()`
Если Вы дергните `os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)` то приложение буду закрыто в любом случае самой ОС по PID, но Вы можете потерять данные, а в случае `sys.exit()` программа Ваша должна уметь корректные обработчики для закрытия всех внутренних процессов, в противном случае приложение останется висеть не закрытым в списке работающих процессов..., но исчезнет из трея....

Answer (score 2):

> Перевод [оригинального ответа со StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54082417/11915565) для русскоязычного сообщества с правками в соответствии с контекстом вопроса от меня.
> Спасибо [@Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4880003/nathan) за развёрнутый ответ!

Имеем сейчас (по крайней мере) пару модулей, свободно доступных для этого:

- [pystray](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pystray)
- [infi.systray](https://github.com/Infinidat/infi.systray)

Я только начал использовать infi.systray в своих проектах, и работает он довольно неплохо. Вот как мало кода вам нужно, чтобы сделать что-то простое (взято из документации модуля):

```py
import sys

from infi.systray import SysTrayIcon


def stop_app(systray):
    sys.exit()


menu_options = (("Выход", None, stop_app),)
systray = SysTrayIcon("icon.ico", "Telegram-бот", menu_options)
systray.start()
```

---

> В написании этого ответа спасибо за помощь автору [оригинального ответа со StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63668905/11915565).

Также от себя добавлю, что если вы используете Windows от 10 и выше, то вам приходятся нативные уведомления Windows, в которых вы можете настроить уведомление, при нажатии на которое приложение будет закрываться. Для этого:

- во-первых, удалите текущую версию **win10toast** из своего окружения, если она установлена (например, `pip uninstall win10toast`).
- во-вторых, установите модифицированную версию **win10toast** (например, `pip install git+https://github.com/Charnelx/Windows-10-Toast-Notifications.git#egg=win10toast`).
- затем вставьте в ваш проект следующий код:

```py
import sys

from win10toast import Toast

toast = ToastNotifier()
toast.show_toast(title='Telegram-бот запущен!', msg='Чтобы выключить бота, нажмите на уведомление', callback_on_click=lambda: sys.exit())
```

Answer (score 0):

Благодарю PaveTranquil и microup. Использовал ответы обоих участников и результат меня пока устраивает. Код от PaveTranquil запускал иконку, но не выполнял необходимую функцию, бот продолжал работать. Код от microup запускал иконку, но бот не выполнял свои функции. Сделал так:

```
import os
from infi.systray import SysTrayIcon
def stop_app(systray):
    os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
menu_options = (("Остановить Бота", None, stop_app),)
systray = SysTrayIcon("telegram.ico", "Telegram Бот", menu_options)
systray.start()
```

Остаётся разобраться как избавиться от кнопки Quit в меню уведомления, которая удаляет значок, но не завершает работу бота.

Comment: Если я пишу очевидную глупость, извините, я в Python с января 2023 года, ещё очень многое не знаю.